# Как создать резиновый баннер в Magento?

Tags: php, magento

Почитал литературу и уроки по созданию статических блоков в Magento, не могу найти подходящего решения для установки баннера в правую колонку. При этом изображение должно быть резиновым, как на большом мониторе сохранять пропорции, так и на планшете. Пробовал через создание статического блока и виджета. Возможно можно как-то напрямую создать блок в hml или phtml файле? Подскажите, пожалуйста! Если вопрос звучит неконкретно, то в диалоге постараюсь объяснить чётче. Ещё нюанс, баннер должен выводится первым в колонке.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

То, какие блоки выводятся, определяется шаблоном и макетом (`layout`). 
На примере `magento 1.9` и шаблона `RWD`, если для раздела каталога используется шаблон `frontend/rwd/default/template/page/3columns.phtml`, то в нём можно найти такую строчку:

```
<div class="col-right sidebar"><?php echo $this->getChildHtml('right') ?></div>
```

Т.е. он пытается получить блоки 'right'.

Далее смотрим в `app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout/catalog.xml` и находим в нём:

```
<default>
    <reference name="right">
        <block type="catalog/product_compare_sidebar" before="cart_sidebar" name="catalog.compare.sidebar" template="catalog/product/compare/sidebar.phtml"/>
    </reference>
</default>
```

Т.е. по умолчанию в правой колонке выводится блок для сравнения товаров. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Блоки "Community poll" и "PayPal" добавляются файлами `paypal.xml` и `poll.xml` (вариантов добавления блоков несколько). Проще всего добавить блок в уже существующий **xml** файл, для каталога это будет `catalog.xml`.

Добавим нужный блок следующим образом:

```
<default>
    <reference name="right">
        <block type="page/html" name="page.right.banner" output="toHtml" template="page/custom/banner.phtml" />
        <block type="catalog/product_compare_sidebar" before="cart_sidebar" name="catalog.compare.sidebar" template="catalog/product/compare/sidebar.phtml"/>
    </reference>
</default>
```

И создадим файл `app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/page/custom/banner.phtml` со своим содержимым:

```
<?php
    $url = Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_SKIN);
?>
<img src="<?php echo $url . 'frontend/rwd/default/images/banners/cat.jpg'; ?>" style="width: 100%">
```

Чистим кеш и получаем:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сортировка блоков определяется параметрами `before="child.block.name"` и `after="child.block.name"`. У блока сравнения есть `before="cart_sidebar"`, поэтому сейчас он выводится выше нашего блока. Можем добавить нашему блоку `before="catalog.compare.sidebar"` и наш блок станет выше.

```
<block type="page/html" name="page.right.banner" output="toHtml" before="catalog.compare.sidebar" template="page/custom/banner.phtml" />
```

Ну, а чтобы баннер был респонсив (тянулся под любое разрешение), это уже задача **css**. Вариантов решения тоже масса, всё зависит от конкретной верстки. Как самый простой вариант, можно для изображения задать `width: 100%`

Comment: Спасибо большое, Danil!!! Как всегда исчерпывающий и понятный ответ!!!:-)

Comment: Единственный момент нужно убрать output="toHtml", это дублирует вывод блока внизу и на всю ширину страницы под футером.